# How to post complex json object in angularjs and spring mvc

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

i want to post complex json object in angular and spring mvc. so wirte this code.
for simple object such as customer data it's work correctly. but for complex object not work and display error "400 bad request".
baskets object may be more than one.
my objects in java

```
public class Data {
   private List<BasketData> baskets;
 }
  public class BasketData {
    private CustomerData customer;
 }

 public class CustomerData {
  private String name;
  private String phone;
  private String mobile;
  private String address;
}
```

and spring controller

```
 public @ResponseBody List<Data> save(@RequestBody List<Data> data){
 }
```

in html page i create form by ng-reeat.

```
      <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
         <input ng-model="item[$index].baskets[$index].customer.phone"/>
         <input ng-model="item[$index].baskets[$index].customer.name"/>
         <input ng-model="item[$index].baskets[$index].customer.mobile"/>
         <input ng-model="item[$index].baskets[$index].customer.address"/>
      </div>
```

and in angularjs controller create this json object

```
  var item = [
    {
        baskets: [
            {
                customer:
                    {
                        phone: "",
                        name: "",
                        mobile: "",
                        address: ""
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
];
 $scope.items.push(item);
 $http.post('/post', $scope.items);
```

Comment: In your JSON, you have a list of customer in baskets. In your Java class, it's a simple Customer in your class BasketData

Comment: @Apédémak i have list of baskest and one have one customer.

Comment: I got this. I just wanna said that in your JSON with the `[ ]`, you have a list of customer instead of a single object. You can have multiple customers in a single basket. I don't know if it's the reason of your problem, but it's possible that the matching with the server isn't OK.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem when I have complex json

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/submitReturn", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

And at the client side from where you are calling that method

```
headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    type:"post",
    data : json,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){}
});
```